# Why does a union involving a conditionally defined property result in looser types than expected?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following TypeScript code:

```
const test = Math.random() < 0.5 ? { a: 1, b: 2 } : {};
```

I would expect the type of this object to be:

```
const test: {
  a: number;
  b: number;
} | {}
```

because this is the strictest type description of it. Either the conditional is true, in which case the object has two properties, or its not and the object has no properties.

Instead, I find the type to be

```
const test: {
  a: number;
  b: number;
} | {
  a?: undefined;
  b?: undefined;
}
```

This seems incorrect to me because there is no scenario in which properties can exist with undefined values.

Another example:

[image]

Here I've declared a type where the items property either does not exist on the object, or exists and is defined. I then inspect the generated type and see that the type has loosened such that items can exist as a property on the object and have a value of undefined.

What am I not understanding about TypeScript's typesafety guarantees?

Comment: `{}` type can accept any object `const foo: {} = {a: 1, b: 2};`. So typescript is not wrong.

Comment: It's not incorrect because `{}` is assignable to `{a?: undefined, b?: undefined}`, so `test` is definitely assignable to this type. The question is why Typescript decides that this is the "[best common type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#best-common-type)" for the two object types. I must admit it's not a case I've seen before, and it's not mentioned in the docs; my best guess is that `{a?: undefined, b?: undefined}` is used because it's equivalent to `{a?: never, b?: never}`, where `never` appears because `a` and `b` aren't properties of the second object.

Comment: Regarding the distinction between a property that isn't present (so you'll get `undefined` when you access it) and a property that is present with the value `undefined`, Typescript doesn't track this distinction unless you enable `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` in the config; this is off by default, and isn't included in `strict`. Enabling that setting gives `{a?: never, b?: never}` instead, which suggests my guess is right; if you prefer that then consider enabling `exactOptionalPropertyTypes`, though be aware it might cause some problems elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript is by default slightly sloppy with optional properties. Specifically it doesn't distinguish properties that don't exist at all from those that are set to `undefined`. Set the option [`exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes) in order to get the more precise type `test: { a: number; b: number } | { a?: never; b?: never }`.